# Moved from room after bad insect bite, but what about the next guy?

Tags: italy, hotels, accommodation, genoa

I am staying in a hotel in Genova for three more nights. The hotel is prepaid by my grant, and leaving is something I don't want.

Last night an insect bit me, and for the first time in my life I got a bruised right hand. Today I requested a room change, since there is no way to get in there again, I will be too afraid. The change was made, but I was told that they are fully booked.

At that time, I was in pain and very eager to get my medicine. As a result, I didn't really process what she told me.

*Now, I am thinking the next guest(s), that must be placed there. I feel guilty. Is there anything I can do?* It seems to me that I have no options now to protect the next people from that nasty insect.

Comment: You can knock on the door and let the person know if they put someone there.

Comment: @The Zealot do you think this is a good idea? It might be too direct for them. Moreover, the other room is an another room, so I feel like I should hide from the staff, if they find me in a wrong floor. However, this is a fair trade off z so I would suggest you to post an answer.

Comment: I would think that the cleaning staff of the hotel would find and dispose of the insect when they cleaned the room, especially if you informed the front desk staff that it was there.

Comment: @Michael Seifert, that would be my hope. How about I ask tomorrow the reception, in a friendly way, if they got rid of it. What do you think?

Comment: @gsamaras By ‘insect’ do you mean something out of the ordinary flying / crawling in the room or something in the bed (eg fleas)? I’d expect most people to be prepared with insect repellant for typical wildlife such as mosquitoes and wouldn’t really expect the hotel to be able to do much about it, but I’d be very annoyed to be bitten by fleas in the bed and would complain to the hotel management immediately

Comment: @Traveller I don't know. I witnessed a big fly and another unidentified insect, which look small. I suspect there must have been another unseen insect. I an in Genoy for business, so I was really worried about what time I would go to bed. I tried killing them, but failed.

Comment: @gsamaras Could have been a sandfly? Their bites are painful and can bruise, and they're small, stealthy buggers. They're also not the sort of thing that stays in one room or that a hotel can really do something about (unlike, say, bedbug infestations - but those bites swell rather than bruise)

Comment: @user568458 it was a big fly. In Greece, those flies are not known to bite. You just have to make sure that they don't land on your food. I made that sure, and since the other insect I saw was looking small, I went to bed. You probably mean the little one, and not the fly I mentioned. Unfortunately I didn't recognize it.

Comment: @gsamaras, it is way more likely for you to have had an allergic or just very bad reaction than for the insect to be very nasty. So care about yourself and do not worry about the next user of the room.

Comment: @Wileke thank for the advice, I am now in the room and recovering. I had never had such an episode before though. Fortunately, the television has Alexander The Great,  so there is something Greek to keep me company. :)